# calling wrong method ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this piece of code :

```
listeners: 
{
    beforerender: function() 
    {
        if (importButton == true) 
        {
            this.menu.add(
            {
                text: 'Import',
                iconCls: 'importIcon',
                listeners: 
                {
                    click: new ifAuthorizing('import')
                }
            })
        }
        this.menu.add(
        {
            text: 'Consultation',
            iconCls: 'searchIcon',
            listeners: 
            {
                click: menuConsultation
            }
        }) 
    }
}
```

that is supposed to add items to a menu when some conditions are OK.

It's working, the button are well added if the conditions matches.

The problem is coming from the

```
listeners: 
{
    click: new ifAuthorizing('import')
}
```

This listener is supposed to be appended to the menu item, but it is triggered during the beforerender event of its parent.

```
function ifAuthorizing(arg) {
    console.log('import')
}
```

The 'import' is displayed in the console logs during the beforerender event, and then if I click on the menu item that is supposed to have a click method, nothing happens.

I would like to know why.

Comment: what happens if you take out the `new` off of it?

Comment: You have a missing brace in your `ifAuthorizing` declaration

Comment: @lascort , if I remove the new it's working, but why ?Yeah, sorry for the missing brace (a ctrl+v mistake :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new ifAuthorizing('import')
```

Here operator **new** tries to create an object and interpretes ifAuthorizing as a constructor. The constructor is called immediately, that's why it fires on beforeRender event. As a result you get some object which is not a copy of function ifAuthorizing, so it can't be called on menu item's event with the desired result.